# Mac：Files can be displayed on the command line but not on the graphical interface

Tags: macos

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14

I created a folder on terminal successfully and type `open .` but I can't find the new folder.I tried to reopen a new finder.I still can't see it.

[image]

But when I type `open test1` and go back to "test" folder in the same finder.The "test1" folder appears.

[image]

I can use the search function on computer to find the image.But when I click show in the folder, it shows nothing.

[image: screenshot2]

It doesn't seem like about permissions.Cause I am a normal user on the terminal.And the permissions of files are as follows.

[image: screenshot3]

When I use preview to choose a image and open, I can see the image.But I can't see it by opening folder in finder. I am sure I  didn't confuse the file path.

[image: screenshot4]

They are not hidden files because they don't start with `.`.

The situation also happens when I download files from website.

After downloading, the folder I chose to save doesn't have the file in the finder(I have opened the new finder).But it shows on the command line.Then I click the `show in finder` function on the website, the files appear.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You're cutting off a few key pieces in your pics.  What is the folder name (directory) in the final Terminal pic?  Show a pic of that folder (type "open ." in that Terminal to open that folder in Finder).  Can you quit Finder and restart, to see if the files show up?  What if you use Terminal to copy one of the files into the same folder, but with a new name (temp.png, etc.)?  My guess is that the files have some hidden attribute, or Finder just doesn't notice they've been created.  Also try "ls -l -@ *png" to see if there are extended attributes, although it doesn't look like it from the pic.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question.Also, when I use Terminal to copy one of the files into the same folder, but with a new name, the situation is the same( I still can't see my images in folder).I don't know what do you mean about extended attributes.can you explain what situation can they lead to?

Comment: MacOS/Darwin includes "extended attributes" that include other ways of marking files as hidden.  But, that `ls` output you showed shows that there are NO extended attributes, which is what I thought/hoped it might be.  So, for some reason, Finder is not detecting/displaying files that are created by non-Finder programs, like Terminal and your browser, but I don't have an answer for that.  Googling for "finder not displaying files" gives a lot of good suggestions, including this one: https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1226031

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! The suggestions you find for me does work.Maybe you can write an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this as a new contributor, but you can actually write your own answer, and accept it.  Not that I don't mind getting points, but I don't actually know what the "right" answer for you was, just provided some help to get you there.  You can "upvote" my comment(s), but otherwise the "right" answer should be listed here explicitly so that others may see it if they have a similar problem.  Glad it's working!  :-)

Comment: My reputation is too low to "upvote" your answer......sad....Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“ Do a 3 finger salute (Command+Option+Escape) and Relaunch the Finder--see if they appear. My guess is that there is some process that is stuck and isn't updating your folder view. ”

Actually the answer is from https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1226031